# Cannot update WorkItems - Reason: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.8) with an on-premise installation of TFS 2017.
In our team a checkin is required to have some associated work item. This worked fine and does still with all of my colleagues.
But when I do a checkin, I get the error message (see title) with every work item I associate. Since checkin works fine, it is just annoying to associate the change sets manually.

I do not use any custom code, so I can't debug any API (as suggested by Shayki Abramczyk) - it's just a matter between VS and TFS. I tried to intercept the communication between VS and TFS, but that did not work yet.

How can I find out which fields are invalid? Is there any type of log where I can research the cause?

Guenter

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save" on associated workitem, but code is checked in regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768141/tf237124-work-item-is-not-ready-to-save-on-associated-workitem-but-code-is-c)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the problem of dan is inside his own code using the TFS API. My problem is in the product itself, so I cannot use the suggested solution for the other question (calling the Validate() method of TFS API) as I don't know which fields are changed by the TFS checkin procedure.

Comment: You can try update the work item via API and use the Validate(), then you will see which field is the problem.

Comment: Shayki, please read my post before answering; as I do not own the code that modifies the work items, I cannot use any API to verify, because I don't know which field to change to produce the error! I need a means to log/intercept the communication between VS2017 anf the TFS server to identify the changed fields ikn the first place...

Comment: You don't need to be the own of the code, you can write your code and retrieve the work item with the API, then check the fields.

Comment: I can only use my own code to check something, when I know what to check...
I can successfully work with all work items, states and fields inside the web frontend of TFS. All of my cvolleagues can work succexssfully from inside Visual Studio - I need to find out which fields VS is trying to alter in TFS - that's my core problem. And "my code" does not help me there...

Comment: The vs version is exactly like your vs colleagues?

Comment: Hi Guys, I solved the problem the MS way: used the command witadmin rebuildcache to clear the client cache - and all worked nicely again.

Comment: Great! you can post in as answer to help another people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much unsuccessful attempts the following command made my day:

```
witadmin rebuildcache
```

It seems the cache had been corrupted by using a TFS production dump as a test environment. After clearing the cache everything works fine again.